# How to configure PostgreSQL to allow TCP/IP connections?

Tags: java, macos, postgresql, heroku, tcp

I'm trying to push a webapp to Heroku, and am having trouble getting Postgres to accept TCP/IP connections. I've gone through all the questions/answers on this topic, and still can't solve this. I'm new to databases/web development and any help is very much appreciated!

In postgresql.conf I’ve changed the listen address variable from localhost to `#listen_addresses = ‘*’`. The port looks correct: `#port = 5432`.

I also added `0.0.0.0` to `pg_hba.conf` (is this the correct order?):

```
# TYPE   DATABASE       USER        ADDRESS          METHOD
local       all         all                           trust
host        all         all          0.0.0.0/0        md5
host        all         all        127.0.0.1/32       trust
host        all         all         ::1/128           trust
```

After adding that address, when I called `postgres` in the terminal, it ran but with a fatal error:

```
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-09-06 16:21:43 PDT
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
FATAL:  database "admin" does not exist
```

When I tried to launch `psql`, the same message:

```
psql: FATAL:  database "admin" does not exist
```

I was able to connect to `psql` through another database: `psql -d template1` and created a new admin database. Then I created the database that I needed for my app, and made sure that it was functional by running my project with Gradle. I've stopped the server completely multiple times during this process to see if changes have been effective.

Heroku logs still show the same issue that I had before changing the Postgres config files:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to
localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct
and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

When I visit http://localhost:5432/, it shows “No data received” with the error “Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data."

Thanks for any help!

Versions: Mac OSX 10.10.5, PostgreSQL 9.4.4, Heroku 3.41.5, Gradle 2.5, Java 1.8.0_51. All installed using Homebrew.

Comment: a few things to consider 1) `listen_addresses` should be uncommented with value you specified 2) after `pg_hba.conf` /  `postgresql.conf` changes are made - configuration should be reloaded in postgres by restarting service or in psql `pg_reload_conf()` 3) you have not indicated connection properties of your app in your question, so try to check them try running `psql -U yourAppUser -d yourDatabase -h hostnameAddressOrDNS` in order to check them.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you trying to use the [Heroku provided database](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) or are you running one of your own? If not Heroku, where is this other Postgres database running (locally, AWS, etc)?

Comment: @codefinger You're right-- I was trying to use my own database. I'm going to try using Heroku's and see how that works out.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you're running your own, independent Postgres database -- is this correct? If you're using Heroku, odds are -- this isn't a great idea.

One of the main benefits of Heroku is that it handles your server maintenance / recovery / etc. for you -- this is what it's primary benefit is =)

With the above in mind, I'd recommend you use [Heroku Postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) instead of running your own Postgres database. Not only is it the largest hosted Postgres service in the world -- it's been around *forever*, is essentially bug free, allows you to do tons of awesome stuff (instantly provision read slaves / backup masters / etc.), and even *has a generous free plan*.

There's really no reason not to use it =)

To get stated with Heroku Postgres, you can simply say:

```
$ heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev
```

This will generate a new database for you that your app can access through a pre-defined environment variable named `DATABASE_URL`. Just give that URL to your web framework / application code, and have it connect to that -- it includes a username/password / etc., and should work easily.

You may also wanna check out the getting started guide for more information: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I'll give it a try and check back when I'm through.